# не отображает текст в виде таймера и вылетает (pyqt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Делаю программу с библиотекой PyQT5, и программа ведёт отсчёт таймера идёт при помощи цикла while и выражения start - time.time(), где старт это time.time(), ниже будет функция, отвечающая за таймер:

```
def timer1_start():
start = time.time()
current_time = time.time() - start
while current_time < 30:
    timer_and_counter.setText(f"00:00:{round(current_time)}")
    current_time = time.time() - start
```

Сам current_time спокойно выводится на консоль, но как я и сказал ранее, в приложении оно не выводится

Данная функция привязана к кнопке, которая отвечает за запуск таймера, при нажатии кнопки, программа зависает и через несколько секунд вылетает окошко, говорящее что приложение не отвечает

Есть ли какие то события в PyQT5 отвечающие за вывод таймеров или что-то типа такого?
При надобности могу скинуть весь код

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Для работы приложения необходим цикл событий. 
Цикл `while current_time < 30: ...` блокирует работу приложения на `30 секунд`. 
Покажите ваш код и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать.